# Applying a filter to multiple loops for days ago

Tags: loop, filters

I'm trying to use a filter that limits the days ago loops pull posts from.

My problem is that I need different day limits for certain loops on the index page and when I duplicate the filter over a second loop, I get an error saying "Cannot redeclare filter_where() (previously declared in ".)

I remove the filter after the first loop that I use it, but that doesn't help. Here are the filters...

```
<?php
  function filter_where($where = '') {
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
  }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
query_posts($query_string);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the filter_where function in your functions.php file in your theme.

```
<?php
function filter_where($where = '') { 
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'"; 
    return $where; 
}
```

Comment: Hmm ok so how do I change the day limit for different loops in the same page once I do that?

Comment: Ok so I just duplicated the function and named it different variations. That's how I was supposed to do it I hope.